# (Clockwork Automaton) construct back to 1 HP with repair spell wand? additional cost, how?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, spell-components

The **Clockwork Automaton** template makes a creature a construct with a soul.

> **[Inorganic Functioning (Ex)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/clockwork-automaton-cr-0#TOC-Inorganic-Functioning-Ex-)**
>
> A clockwork automaton can only be repaired by spells that affect the construct type such as rapid repair. In addition a clockwork automaton is not subject to massive damage, are not subject to the rules for damaging items.
>
> If a clockwork automaton reaches 0 HP or below, the automaton will ***case*** functioning and be treated as unconscious. Additional damage may be inflicted while an automaton is unconscious, but it cannot be truly destroyed by normal means. An automaton may be restored by use of the make whole spell, the Craft Construct feat, or other repair spells for constructs. Regardless of the method used, the repair consumes an additional 2,000 GP in material cost, plus an additional 500 GP in for every hit point below 0 and will leave the automaton at 1 HP. All repairs must be performed no later than 1 day / character level, otherwise the cost increases to 6,000 GP in materials and 1,000 GP for every hit point below 0. Some aspect of the original automaton must be present for repairs to commence, and once restored additional parts not used in the restoration go inert. An automaton can be reincarnated once below 0 hp, provided the spirit is willing.
>
> If the automaton has been melted down or reduced to dust by disintegrate or similar spell, the soul is unbound from the body and the automaton is dead, as per organic creatures in the same state. They may only be brought back by a carefully worded wish or miracle spell, provided the spirit is willing, at which point the automaton is restored back to life in full condition with no extra cost or penalties.

(I think "*case*" should be "*cease*".)

My questions:

1. Can sombody else use a "wond of *Make Whole*" on it to put it at 1 HP?
2. How would the additional material be added?

Comment: the construct is below 0 HP!

Comment: It's become clear to me that *I have no idea what you are asking*. Who is "someone else"? Who are they *not*, for that matter? Not the automaton itself? What do you mean? It says right in the text that *make whole* "or other repair spells" work, so I'm not understanding what the question there is. For 2, what do you mean "how"? It's the same as crafting: left up to the player/group/DM to describe as appropriate to the setting, not defined by the rules.

Comment: "someone else"="anyone but the Clockwork Automaton creature itself" and on "how", what I was looking for was the thing you just wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, anyone may use a *make whole* effect or similar (or the Craft skill) to repair a clockwork automaton. If the clockwork automaton is below 0 HP, it *must* be someone else, since the automaton is unconscious. It does not matter if the effect comes from a spell, a wand, or whatever.

When the clockwork automaton is below 0 HP, the effect of *make whole* et al. changes; instead of repairing some amount of damage, the effect resets the automaton’s HP to 1, no matter how far below 0 it was or how much the effect should be repairing otherwise. It also costs more than it typically would.

The extra cost depends on how much *below zero* the automaton is at the time. Specifically, if the automaton’s HP is *n* and *n*<0, the cost is 2000+500×(−*n*) gold pieces.

For example, if the automaton is at −7 HP (i.e. *n*=−7), the cost is 2000+500×(7)=5500 gp.

This extra cost is for raw materials used in the repair work. What exactly the material is, how it is procured, and how it is used in the repair work is left undefined: up to the player, the group, and/or the DM to decide and describe. For the most part, if you have the money, you should be able to get the materials and perform the work, though different games/groups/DMs have different opinions on that. Some will allow you to just deduct the appropriate number of gold pieces, others will make you actually go roleplay searching for a provider, negotiating a price, and purchasing the materials.

Comment: The amount is irrelevant, the question is about the how to do it. It doesn't matter if it would cast 3,000gp or 5,500gp if you have an amount of 10,000gp on raw material. If you would already have the material you wouldn't need to pay it, it would just ... . however it happens. which was question number 2 and you answered that question to. You just need have the raw materials at hand.